# Counter Up Number displays different amount than specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I got the following section on this websit: https://spineandsportsmed.com/

[image: counter issue]

We changed the **550+** number to **775+** but amount doesn't change.

Cleared cache. Tried on several browsers. TOR Browser too. Nothing yet.

Same issues with **14 clinics**. As a quickfix: hardcoded the number 14 but we really want the counter up working.

**Code for reviews:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="<?= $classes->panel ?>--box">
      <h1><span id="reviews">775</span>+</h1>
      <p>5-Star Reviews</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Code for Clinics:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="<?= $classes->panel ?>--box">
      <!-- <h1 id="clinics">14</h1> -->
      <h1>14</h1>
      <p>Clinics</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

At the topf of this code i found the following which i don't understand what it is
 and **no other reference to a javascript library or jquery** on the server or outside so i could check the issue.

```
<?php
use Roots\Sage\Assets;
use Roots\Sage\Panels;

$classes = Panels\get_panel_classes('trust', Panels\get_unique_panel_id(), 'copter--home__');
?>
```

Not sure if this is implemented with JQuery or Javascript, when i used the developer tools on browser nothing is displayed

I would be more than gratefull if you could give me a little of what could e the cause of the issue of where can i seek more using the developer tools. Thanks.

Comment: There is too little information to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS file main.js on line 68 these values are hardcoded:

```
var patients  = new CountUp('patients', 0, 28500, 0, 2.5, options);
var reviews   = new CountUp('reviews', 0, 550, 0, 2.5, options);
var clinics   = new CountUp('clinics', 0, 11, 0, 2.5, options);
```

Change hardcoded values to real values from your html by id:

```
var reviews   = new CountUp('reviews', 0, $('#reviews').html(), 0, 2.5, options);
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I indeed found that but also i found another main.js So i put the same sample you suggested. It seems it stays the same with same values. How can i debbug this myself with the developer tools on the browsers? please, thank you for your help